# xpath help cannot extract second element

Tags: xpath

Sorry very new to xpath

```
<figure id="image0" data-zoom-src="//www.XXX.com/2afb588db7c3c044a6e7594fe94f1c3b.jpg">
```

I am trying to extract `data-zoom-src` of this using xpath.

Not sure how to achieve this tried numerous options but stump .

If anyone know of great xpath reference as well

Thanks for help in advance

Darz

Comment: post an example of what you trying to extract. Otherwise we have a hard time answering.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to get the value of `data-zoom-src` you can use `string()`:

```
string(figure/@data-zoom-src)
```

or, depending on the location of the figure element, e.g.

```
 string(//figure/@data-zoom-src)
```

returns

```
//www.XXX.com/2afb588db7c3c044a6e7594fe94f1c3b.jpg
```

It may depend on the XPath parser that you use as I had to add a closing `</figure>` tag to get the result.

For the question about recommendable XPath references: Questions on Stackoverflow to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. But you can click on the `xpath` tag label and then on "learn more" to get to the [Stackoverflow XPath tag wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xpath/info). There you'll find some useful links and reliable information.